# Updating system's "Olson" Timezone Database Version

Tags: linux, redhat, timezone, pecl

My phpinfo() shows:

```
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
```

Instead of installing the pecl module, isnt it better if I can update the system timezone database / system?

How can I do that?

I'm ona RHEL5/CentOS system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `tzdata` package.

Comment: that would do it for the system?

Comment: That will update anything that can reasonably called the "system timezone database".

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how can I check the system timezone version? And I assume yum install tzdata should work fine to update?

Comment: `rpm -q tzdata`, and if there's an update then yum will find it.

Comment: This is slightly weird... rpm -q tzdata says: tzdata-2010l-1.el5
But ftp://elsie.nci.nih.gov/pub/ shows: tzcode2010m.tar.gz (notice the "m" version).

Comment: When I try doing  yum install tzdata it says: Package tzdata-2010l-1.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Red Hat hasn't gotten around to packaging 2010m yet, which is why CentOS doesn't have it. You can either wait a bit longer, or rebuild the SRPM yourself.

Comment: For me it works in CentOS 6 (package: tzdata-2011l-4.el6.noarch) and doesn't work in CentOS5 (package: tzdata-2011g-1.el5)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **CentOS 6**, then just upgrade package:

```
[sudo] yum update tzdata
```

For **CentOS 5**, copy timezone file from CentOS 6 to your /etc/localtime on CentOS 5 and wait for upgrade being released